# The name doesn't exists in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a custom `ToggleButton` for the header of an `Expander` with an additional button to delete the element of the expander (I have a listview of expanders).

The error I get is:

```
"The name 'CustomToggleButton' doesn't exists in namespace 'clr-namespace:BoxEngine.BoxPreviewControls;assembly=BoxPreviewControls'"
```

This is the header of the theme.xaml file

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:modules="clr-namespace:BoxEngine.BoxPreviewControls;assembly=BoxPreviewControls">
```

These are the WPF lines in my theme file that generate the errors:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
                 TargetType="{x:Type modules:CustomToggleButton}">
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
...

<Style x:Key="Expander.ctlPrintData" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
...
                            <modules:CustomToggleButton
                                x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                Template="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}"
                                Background="Transparent" />
...
</Style>
```

And finally this is the CustomToggleButton class:

```
namespace BoxEngine.BoxPreviewControls
{
    public partial class CustomToggleButton : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton
    {
        private Button delete_button_;

        // get the button objects as the templete is applied and add click event handlers
        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            delete_button_ = GetTemplateChild("btnRemovePrint") as Button;
            delete_button_.Click += toggleBtnRemovePrint_Click;
        }

        // event exposed to container
        public static readonly RoutedEvent OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_ClickedEvent =
            EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_Click", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomExpander));

        // expose and raise 'OnBtnRemovePrint_ClickedEvent' event
        public event RoutedEventHandler OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_Click
        {
            add { AddHandler(OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_ClickedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_ClickedEvent, value); }
        }

        private void toggleBtnRemovePrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(OnToggleBtnRemovePrint_ClickedEvent));
        }
    }

...
} //namespace
```

I don't know if it matters but the class and the theme are defined in the BoxPreviewControls project, its a WPF controls library. The WPF application is in another project.

I saw a lot of similar questions but I didn't find the solution yet, so any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

I closed all files in visual studio, restarted it and rebuilt the solution.
Now I get a new error (with the last one, not in place of it):

```
"Cannot find the public type 'CustomToggleButton' from the type reference"
```

**EDIT 2**

I removed the assembly in the XAML header for BoxPreviewControls and now it works. Do you know why??

Now the header is:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:modules="clr-namespace:BoxEngine.BoxPreviewControls">
```

Is it because I load the theme in code this way?

```
ResourceDictionary resDict = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("/BoxPreviewControls;component/Themes/theme.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: We can't see if CustomToggleButton is defined in the right namespace or not.

Comment: Is your CustomToggleButton class in a scope `namespace BoxEngine.BoxPreviewControls`?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a "false-positive" error? The XAML editor is very prone to that kind of errors. Did you try your control and is it working?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Yes the namespace is correct, also the auto-completion suggest me the class name, but I cannot build because of the error!

Comment: Why your `CustomToggleButton` class is `Partial`? It looks like a `CustomControl` not an `UserControl`

Comment: I solved the problem, see my Edit 2. What was wrong?

Comment: You don't need to specify the assembly name in case you are referring to components in the same assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the assembly in the XAML header for BoxPreviewControls and now it works.

See **EDIT 2** for details